# C# How to use Directory White Spaces into process.arguements?

Tags: c#, process, directory, arguments

The program created utilizes a 3rd party tool to generate a log file.

However the arguments provided for the the tool requires various files from Directory locations as part of generating the logs. Therefore the main argument of `@"-r C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat -d C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + " -p runmru";` would be used to generate the logs.

May someone advise on how to make the arguments of "C:\System Volume Information\" be processed by the system with the white spaces in placed? Thanks!

The codes:

```
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\test\ftk\ripxp\ripxp.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-r C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat -d C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + " -p runmru";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.Start();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` by appending a `\` to them (`\"`) - for normal strings, or doubling them (`""`) for verbatim string literals (those starting with `@`):

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-r C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat -d ""C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + @""" -p runmru";
```

Comment: The restoreFolder.Name is a system name I thinker perhaps you placed an extra " or \ in the wrong area? even the above codes are showing errors already.

Comment: @JavaNoob - Yeah. You were mixing verbatim string with non verbatim strings... Each needs different escaping. Corrected...

Answer (score 2):

Wrap that path in double quotes:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-r C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat -d ""C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + @""" -p runmru";
```

Comment: The system is showing that there is a unclosed " near the triple """.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-r C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat -d C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + " -p runmru";
```

should be

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-r ""C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat"" -d ""C:\System Volume Information\""" + restoreFolder.Name + " -p runmru";
```

Comment: Reps up for answer but try not to use too much "" cause its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the question, you can wrap the name with quotes:

```
"... \"C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + "\"..."
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use a string.Format along with the Path class:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-r C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat -d C:\System Volume Information\" + restoreFolder.Name + " -p runmru"
```

can be rewritten to be a lot cleaner as follows:

```
string ntuser = @"C:\test\ftk\ntuser.dat";
var args = Path.Combine(@"C:\System Volume Information\", "restoreFolder.Name");

var outs = string.Format("-r {0} -d {1} -p runmru", ntuser, args);
outs.Dump();
```